# Getting Discrete Value supplied to continuous scale while using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, rjson

I have the below data:

```
library(rjson)
library(ggplot2)


l='[{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"weather", "value": 10},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"bad", "value": 14},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"failure", "value": 20},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"not", "value": 1},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"search", "value": 24},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"esrs", "value": 2},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"issue", "value": 1},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "honda", "features":"errors", "value": 30},

{"a": "abc", "date": "20190510","model": "ford", "features":"ice", "value": 12},
{"a": "xyz", "date": "20190509", "model": "honda", "features":"summer", "value":18},
{"a": "xyz", "date": "20190507", "model": "ford", "features":"hot", "value":14},

{"a": "abc", "date": "20190506","model": "ford", "features":"search", "value": 20},
{"a": "abc", "date": "20190510","model": "honda", "features":"400", "value": 18},
{"a": "xyz", "date": "20190509", "model": "ford", "features":"fail", "value":24},
{"a": "xyz", "date": "20190507", "model": "honda", "features":"200", "value":15}]'
```

And when I use this data in the form of dataframe to plot bar graph between features and value using below code:

```
l = fromJSON(l)
df = data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))
ggplot(df, aes(y=features, x=value))
```

I get the below error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

What I am doing here wrong?

Comment: I did not run your code, but I suspect that all of your variables are factors. If this is true, you should convert the appropriate ones to numeric prior to calling `ggplot`. You can check with `sapply(dat, class)` where dat is the name of your data.frame.

Comment: It shows “list” for every variable.

Comment: I am new to R. Can you help in changing their class?

Comment: It looks like the `fromJSON`  function has a simplify argument. Set this to TRUE. Then, if you are lucky, the returned object will be a list of character vectors. Then your code will result in the factor situation I mentioned above. If yes, use `dat$numVar <- as.numeric(dat$numVar)` replacing dat and numVar with appropriate names to convert each factor variable to a numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had luck using `jsonlite`'s `fromJSON`:

```
l = jsonlite::fromJSON(l) 
ggplot(l,aes(y=features, x=value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Edit:

Here's a bar graph. Note that there are two "search" values, stacked here by default.

```
ggplot(l,aes(x=features, y=value)) + 
  geom_col(color = "white") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or if you want them sorted, I like `forcats::fct_reorder`; but note that it's sorting by individual values, not total values; wasn't sure how you wanted to treat the two in "search":

```
ggplot(l,aes(x=forcats::fct_reorder(features, value), y=value)) + 
  geom_col(color= "white") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get bar graph?

Comment: @user15051990. There are many (almost 30k) questions related to `ggplot2` on SO. I suspect one or two relate to bar graphs.

Comment: I got it finally. Thanks!